# How to fill path in Illustrator with average color (like in Ps)?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, path, fill

So i have made triangle path in Illustrator and I want to fill it with the average color of that area. It's possible in Photoshop with Filter>Blur>Average. Is there an option like that in Ai?

Comment: I'm not aware of anything similar in Illustrator.

Comment: There is a near duplicate question some where on GD.Se that used a script to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think theres something like that on illustrator but you can always make a small mosaic and use one of the colours you get:
Go to: Object>create an object mosaic and choose a small number (2 or 3)
If the option is unavailable go to Object>rasterize and when the object is rasterized you'll be able to make a mosaic.